# IOS apply CAlayer to all UILabel layers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I need to apply CAlayer which I did to all my UIlabels on my view

I have 6 UIlabels on my view and I did a CAlayer as below code and want to apply this layer to all my UIlabels

```
CALayer *lay=[CALayer layer];
lay.borderWidth=2;
lay.borderColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;

[out_lat_min.layer addSublayer:lay];
```

one of my UIlabel called out_lat_min

but not work, could you support me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a 'style' of label that you use frequently, the best pattern to employ is a category on UILabel. This isn't a behavior change, so subclassing is not the right answer.

**UILabel+MyCompany.m**

```
+ (UILabel *)borderedLabel {
   UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   [label.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
   [label.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor];
   return label;
}
```

Then, in your code, use this method to create labels wherever you need labels with this behavior, eg:

```
UILabel *label1 = [UILabel borderedLabel];
```

If there are other needs, such as varying the color or width of the label, modify the category method to take arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "apply" a CALayer to a UIView. Each UIView has it's own layer. If you want to apply that color to multiple UIViews' layers, you just have to do it. Like this:

```
for (UIView* x in anArrayOfUIViews)
{
    x.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    x.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
}
```

Furthermore, a CALayer can't be a sublayer of more than one other layer. That's just the way it works.

Comment: I need to apply on the 6 labels only not all labels in my view

Answer (score 0):

Do a for loop for all your UILabels this way:

```
for (UILabel *label in [self.view subviews]) {
        [label.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
        [label.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor];
    }
```

The for loop let you take control of each single UILabel in self.view and then you can change its layer.

Remember to import Quartzcore

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

EDIT: If you want to change the layer by method you can do

```
- (void)applyLayerToLabel:(UILabel *)aLabel
{
    [aLabel.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [aLabel.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor];
}
```

Then call it when needed this way:

```
[self applyLayerToLabel:theNameOfTheLabelYouWantToChange];
```

Comment: but i need to call the layer for each UIlabel by method

Comment: it works on all items on view (labels, text and buttons), I need only only on some labels

Comment: also I need to apply on the 6 labels only not all labels in my view

Comment: "but i need to call the layer for each UIlabel by method" does this mean that you want to set layer calling a method? If so take a look at my EDIT.